# bxslider: scroll to certain slider on page load

Tags: bxslider

I have a slider of 40 slides with 13 current slides visible.
I want to jump to a certain slide on page load.
For example: page1 - load slide 1 first / page25 - load slide 25 first.
Thanks All.

Thats my solution:

```
    // calculate starting slider
    var hActive = $('.h-active');
    var hIndex = hActive.index();
    var startingSlider;
    if (hIndex <= 12) {
        startingSlider = 0;
    } else if (hIndex >= 13 && hIndex <= 25) {
        startingSlider = 1;
    } else if (hIndex >= 26 && hIndex <= 38) {
        startingSlider = 2;
    } else {
        startingSlider = 3;
    }
    // h-slider animation
    $('.h-slide').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('h-active');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('h-active');
    });
    $('.h-slide').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('h-active');
        hActive.addClass('h-active');
    });
    // h-slider call
    $('.h-slider').bxSlider({
        pager: false,
        controls: true,
        minSlides: 13,
        maxSlides: 13,
        slideWidth: 80,
        nextSelector: '#h-next',
        prevSelector: '#h-prev',
        nextText: '<i class="h-next"></i>',
        prevText: '<i class="h-prev"></i>',
        speed: 1000,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        startSlide: startingSlider
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var bx = $(".bxslider").bxSlider({
   startSlide: 24
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [options](http://bxslider.com/options) page on bxslider site.

the documentation states that we can pass the starting slide number when initialising

> **startSlide**
>
> Starting slide index (zero-based)
>
> **default:** 0 **options:** integer

Since you have not mentioned any programming language here,I am assuming you can get the page number in JS variable like `pagenum` which can be assigned a value before `bxslider` in initialization like below:

```
var pagenum;
//set pagenum here
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  startSlide: pagenum?pagenum:0;
  captions: true
});
```